# Getting random words from list python

Tags: python, string, list, random

I want to get two words but I only get one. What should I change?
Here's the code:

```
import random

puntos = ['Norte' , 'Sur' ,'Este' , 'Oeste']

res = random.choice(puntos) #choice returns without [''], choices returns with ['']

print(res)
```

Comment: Use `random.choices()` and specify the number of words to choose.

Comment: [`res = random.choices(puntos, k=2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices). If you want the choices to be unique, [`res = random.sample(puntos, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: and how do I get them without brackets and quotes?

Comment: They return lists of `k-length`, so you could destructure like `a, b = random.sample(puntos, 2)`, whereas printing `res` just prints out the entire list (or what Python defaults to be the string representation of a list).

Comment: Nothing is returning "brackets and quotes". You are getting *a list*, and you are welcome to directly references items in that list if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ways of printing 2 values without '[' like you want

**Example 1:**

```
import random

puntos = ['Norte' , 'Sur' ,'Este , Oeste'] 
res1 = random.choice(puntos)
res2 = random.choice(puntos)

print(res1, res2)
```

**Example 2:**

```
import random

puntos = ['Norte' , 'Sur' ,'Este , Oeste'] 
res1, res2 = random.choices(puntos, k=2)

print(res1, res2)
```

**Example 3:**

```
import random

puntos = ['Norte' , 'Sur' ,'Este , Oeste'] 
res = random.choices(puntos, k=2)

print(res[0], res[1])
```

**Example 4: Concatenating two words into one string**

```
import random

puntos = ['Norte' , 'Sur' ,'Este , Oeste'] 
res = random.choice(puntos) + ' ' + random.choice(puntos)

print(res)
```

If this does not answer your question then I need a clearer question.

Always remember to check the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice